# Mvc Kendo grid - Doesn't show any data that returned from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

What i am trying to do   on Kendo grid is to pass selected column's id  to controller and returned data will be datasource of 2nd kendo grid on same page without any page load or refresh.

Everthing works well on server side.Desired data Data will be returned to view as json format but 2nd grid cannot show the data.

Js:

```
    e.preventDefault();
        var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));
      //Data that coming from kendo grid's selected column
       var code = dataItem.CODE;
       // alert(code);

        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/Administrator/DefinitionDetailRead/",
                     dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                         transport: {
                             read: {
                                 url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                                 data: { DefinitionCode: code },
                                 dataType: "json"
                             },
                             update: {
                                 url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                 dataType: "json"
                             },
                             destroy: {
                                 url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                 dataType: "json"
                             },
                             create: {
                                 url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                 dataType: "json"
                             },

                         },
                         //batch: true,
                         pageSize: 9,
                         schema: {
                             model: {
                                 ID: "ID",
                                 fields: {
                                     ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                     DESCRIPTION: { validation: { required: true } }


                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     });

        $("#detailsGrid").kendoGrid({

            dataSource: dataSource,
             attributes: {

                style: "padding-left: 0px; font-size: 14px"
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh: false,
                pageSizes: false,
                buttonCount: 5
            },

            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "DESCRIPTION",
                    title: "DESCRIPTION",
                    //filterable: {
                    //    ui: titleFilter
                    //},
                    width: "200px"
                },

                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operation", width: "100px" }],
            editable: "popup"
        });
```

Controller: Everthing works here.

```
public ActionResult DefinitionDetailRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string DefinitionCode)
    {
        DataSourceResult result = null;
        var lang = CultureHelper.GetCulture();
        using (var client = SoapProxyFactory.CreateDSrvGDSoapClient())
        {
            var pSize = request.PageSize;
            var pIndex = request.Page;
            var totalsize = client.GetDefinitionDetailsTotalCount(DefinitionCode, lang);
            var dataresult = client.GetDefinitionDetails(DefinitionCode, lang, false);
            var items = dataresult.RootResults;
            result = items.ToDataSourceResult(request, totalsize, null);

        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    #endregion


    }
```

Json Data that coming from controller :

{"Data":[{"ExtensionData":{},"CODE":"ABNORMAL","CODETYPE":null,"COUNT":0,"DESCRIPTION":"Abnormal (check under Resp)","ENTRYDATE":null,"ID":"1b0a0cd8-8fed-4b34-9054-1e73942a16d2","ISACTIVE":false,"ISDEFAULT":false,"ISSELECTED":false,"LANG":null,"NOTE1":null,"NOTE2":null,"ORDERINDEX":null,"PARENTDESCRIPTION":null,"PARENTID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","REFERENCEID":"3df1f5d7-bc04-4554-bf01-1a9d5b95eebb","VALUE":null}

Comment: Just so you know. You can call return Json(dataresult.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); and the paging/size will be calculated for you.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you click the column on grid 1, the event fires, but grid 2 never loads. The Json snippet you posted: did that actually come through as a result of the click on grid 1, or did you capture that some other way? Bottom line is, are you able to confirm that the click event and the datasource binding is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not saying where in the returned data is actually the array with the data.

Your `model` definition should be:

```
    schema: {
        data: "Data",
        model: {
            ID: "ID",
            fields: {
                ID: { 
                    editable: false, 
                    nullable: true
                },
                DESCRIPTION: { 
                    validation: { required: true }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I've added `data: "Data"` informing KendoUI Grid that need to check `Data`.

Your example modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZEndW/

Comment: Worked.I missed  (data: "Data")  on demo page.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type of the dataSource to be "aspnet-mvc". Before that make sure that you have loaded the kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js file.

Also you have to specify the schema configuration.

It should look something like this:

```
 "dataSource": {
                "transport": {
                    "prefix": "",
                    "read": {
                        "url": ""
                    }
                },
                "pageSize": 20,
                "page": 1,
                "total": 0,
                "type": "aspnetmvc-ajax",
                "schema": {
                    "data": "Data",
                    "total": "Total",
                    "errors": "Errors",
                    "model": {
                        "fields": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "quantity": {
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```